# OWA 2003 - Can't open messages

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

I received an SMS from one of my bosses today telling me that he is able to log on to OWA and can see his messages listed but is unable to open those messages. This makes no sense to me, as the messages in the list are affectively nothing more than regular URLs. Nevertheless, I must follow up on his report/complaint.

I've tested it on Windows and Mac, using an assortment of browsers, and it all works fine for me. Unfortunately, while I'm in Australia the boss is currently in the Maldives, using an Internet kiosk. This obviously makes it a bit difficult for me to see if it's a problem at his end, either technical or user related. I must add that in common with many senior managers this one is quit ignorant when it comes to using computers.

Has anyone ever experienced such a problem or can suggest why it might be. My own guess is that it's pebcac but am prepared to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your boss know about pop-up blocking software?

When opening messages from OWA it opens up another window - which looks like a pop-up to most blocking software including IE.

Comment: Tell him to try holding down control while he opens a message.  If it is any of the common pop up blockers that will temporarily disable it and allow him to see the message.

Comment: No, he doesn't know about pop-up blockers and I must admit I'd never given that a thought. I'll no doubt get a call from him tomorrow (Monday) and will try to walk him through it.